# postfix: relay access denied. How to fix it?

Tags: linux, postfix, dovecot

I've been fiddling with `main.cf` file for a long time but still couldn't find why. I've set up an email server with this tutorial [Email with Postfix, Dovecot and MariaDB on CentOS 7](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql-on-centos-7)

This is the part about postfix:

```
myhostname = server.example.com
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
inet_interfaces = all
message_size_limit = 30720000
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
virtual_maildir_extended = yes
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

Now within my server, I could send emails from user1@example.com to user2@example.com, I could receive emails from user@gmail.com, but I couldn't send an email to user@gmail.com. I got an error: `Relay access denied`. Is there anything I should change?

---

**EDIT:**

This is from `/var/log/maillog`

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[(Server's IP)]: 454 4.7.1 <user@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<user1@example.com> to=<user@gmail.com> proto=SMTP
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post relevant maillog LINES when rejection happened.

Comment: @masegaloeh updated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Notice this part in `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks ...
```

So smtpd only permits IP addresses from `mynetworks` to relay emails.

What you need to do is to add your IP to `mynetworks`. For example, if your IP address is 192.168.1.123, change the parameter to

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.123
```

Then you can send emails successfully.

Comment: More detail/explanation would improve your answer

Comment: It worked after trying many postfix configurations, but does anybody knows why Mozilla Thunderbird works without this setting?

Comment: maybe because you have set up smtp authentication within thunderbird?