# SMTP send error Client does not have permission to submit mail to this server. The server response was: 4.7.1 : Relay access denied

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, postfix, smtp, relay

This error comes on my server when I am sending mail outside my domain like to Google, Microsoft, etc. Below is my Postfix config file.

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
#postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 3.6 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 3.6



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.allishere.co.in
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, allishere.co.in, mail.allishere.co.in, localhost.allishere.co.in, localhost
#relayhost = [gritfy-com.mail.protection.outlook.com]:25
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all


smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination,permit_sasl_authenticated
```

Comment: Whoes response? Yours postfix to your mua? External mta's? Post postfix logs here

Answer (score -1):

Add you networks addresses from where you send mail with Mail User Agent so your postfix accept mail from the users

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 your_network_here
```

Or use SMTP authentication in your MUAs.
Also check these.
[postfix: relay access denied. How to fix it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/711588/postfix-relay-access-denied-how-to-fix-it)
https://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#relay

Comment: Please explain  your links with a summary